# Can't write those ‘*’ displayed in R with listing package

Tags: listings

I have some trouble with those ‘*’ displayed sometimes in R. I want to include a code with some using listing package. Here is my code

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\lstdefinestyle{Console}{
belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
breaklines=true,
xleftmargin=\parindent,
language=R,
showstringspaces=false,
upquote = true,
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
inputencoding=utf8,
}

\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}[style=Console]
##   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
\end{lstlisting}
```

And here is the error

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �\lst@FillFixed@\lst@EC� (U+207C0)...
```

Need help !

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) Are you sure the problem is not the quotes? Those are utf8 left and right quotes, try apostrophes instead.

Comment: Yes, the problem is the quotes. My problem is I don't want to replace manually those type of quotes with normal quotes, because R always displays those ones. In verbatim environment it does work (latex compile), but not in listings environment.

Comment: Listings really do not like two byte encodings. But you should be able to get around this using the literate key (I think). Look around at the site for solutions of getting utf8 into listings, there should various. Not at a pc right now so I  cannot help with an explicit example

Comment: Ok thank you, I tried with literate key, it works for special characters like é or ç but I can't figure out for those special quotes. I'll continue my research